# Problem with prove $f$ is constant with derivatives.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives

i got a problem with this exercise:

Be $f:\;\mathbb{R\rightarrow\mathbb{R}}$ a function such that

$|f(x)-f(y)|\leq(x-y)^{2}$, $\forall x,y\in\mathbb{R}$

Prove $f$ is constant.

Well... i was thinking about make this exercise for reduction to absurdity. I suppose exist $c\in(x,y)$ such that $f'(c)\neq 0$ if that happen then $f(x)\neq f(y)$ for $x,y \in \mathbb R$. Some ideas? please help :l i'm stuck in this exercise.

Comment: What can you say about the limit $\lim\limits_{y \to x} \frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}$ ? Then what about the derivative of $f$ ? (Prove that it exists and is $0$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to show that $f$ is differentiable. And, in the same step, one can show that the derivative is zero:
$$
\left|\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}-0\right|=\frac{|f(y)-f(x)|}{|y-x|}\leq\frac{|y-x|^2}{|y-x|}=|y-x|.
$$
Then
$$
\lim_{y\to x}\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}=0
$$
for all $x$, i.e., $f'(x)$ exists for all $x$ and $f'(x)=0$. Now you can use the Mean Value Theorem to show that $f$ is constant.

Answer (score 1):

Note that by the definition of the derivative is $$f'(x) = \lim_{x \rightarrow y} \frac{f(x) - f(y)}{x -y}, $$
which implies that $$| f'(x) | =\lim_{x \rightarrow y} \left| \frac{f(x) - f(y)}{x - y} \right| = \lim_{x \rightarrow y} \frac{|f(x) - f(y)|}{|x - y|} ...$$

Now can you use your hypotheses to show that the derivative of $f(x)$ is equal to 0?

Answer (score 1):

$$|f(x) - f(y)| \leq (x-y)^2 \iff |f(x) - f(y)| \leq |x-y|^2 \iff \left|\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}\right|\leq |x-y|$$

If we let $t = y-x$ then;

$$\lim_{t \to 0} \ \frac{f(x+t)-f(x)}{t} = \lim_{x \to y} \ \frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x} \leq \lim_{x \to y} |x-y| = 0$$

i.e

$$|f'(x)|  =\lim_{x \to y}\left|\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}\right| \leq \lim_{x \to y} \ |x-y| = 0$$

and so $f'(x) = 0, \forall x$ i.e $f$ is constant.

Comment: You lost some absolute values. You also don't know *a priori* that the limit exists, so you can't just write an inequality on limits.

Comment: Yeah, I seen right away this function was lipshitz with constant $1$ (even more, differentiable) so I knew the limit existed.

Comment: What *you* knew isn't relevant. You're supposed to write a correct analytic proof here :P

Comment: Actually the limit existing and what its value is, is done all at once with the inequality. I present the limit, which is $\geq 0$ and show that its $\leq 0$ i.e it is zero. Then by definition, I know that this limit is the derivative. So, two birds with one stone. Where the elements of this argument should be placed, are personal preference.

Comment: I totally disagree. If we're going to post a complete solution, it should be modeling correct mathematics and good teaching. Otherwise we're just teaching other people to write garbage. I'm fine with giving a hint (as I often do) and choosing not to write a complete solution. In fact, I prefer that. But a flawed solution is not helpful to all the readers of the site.

Comment: How do you gauge if your hint is useful?(rhetorical) But, I've fixed the "errors".